# extract file log from iphone

Tags: ios, iphone

i would like to know if there is a way to extract log files from an iphone (as iMazing)
I would to write a code to extract these files (for example history calls)

edit: I think use python as language, but it's not mandatory

Sorry for my bad english.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should edit your question to specify at least wich language you want to use.

Comment: Done @CheshireCat